# Update TextView once alertdialog is dismissed

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an activity (called DiscoverActivity) that has the following distance `TextViews`:

[image]

Once the users click on the distance, the following `AlertDialog` opens:

[image]

Now, I had like that once the users click on the `Done` button, that it will dismiss the `AlertDialog` and update the `TextView` on `DiscoverActivity`.

How can I update it?

Right now when I click Done and dismiss it shows the same value until I move between activities and return.

My code to the Done button:

```
Btn_Done.setOnClickListener( view -> {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences( AppConstants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE ).edit();
    editor.putInt( AppConstants.PREF_RADIUS, seekbar.getProgress() );
    editor.apply();
    dialog.dismiss();
} );
```

And this is what I call in my onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences dist_settings = getSharedPreferences( AppConstants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE );
nearMeRadius = dist_settings.getInt( AppConstants.PREF_RADIUS, 300 );
TextView tv_NearRadius = findViewById( R.id.tv_NearRadius );
tv_NearRadius.setText( getString( R.string.ActivityDiscover_NearMeRadius, nearMeRadius ) );
tv_NearRadius.setOnClickListener( v -> {
    PopUps popUps = new PopUps();
    popUps.popDistanceDialog( DiscoverActivity.this );
} );
```

Comment: onCreate() is called during the creation of the activity. For this reason the value is not getting updated as there is no code to update it once the dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Any method including shared prefrences will only work once until activity is refreshed but when you dismiss a dialog the activity isn't refreshed.

So, you have 2 options

- Search for a way to refresh the activity once the done button in the alert dialog is clicked to dismiss the dilaog.
- Or you can just keep everything the same but when the user clicks done button it changes the text of the activity.

In order to do the second point sense it is much easier you can just do:

```
Btn_Done.setOnClickListener( view -> {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences( AppConstants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE ).edit();
    editor.putInt( AppConstants.PREF_RADIUS, seekbar.getProgress() );
    editor.apply();
    TextView txtView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.text); // this points to the textview in the activity you want to change
        txtView.setText("Hello");
    dialog.dismiss();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface,

```
interface SomeInfy(){
void updateText(String text);
}
```

Implement an interface to your DiscoveryActivity and override updateText()

```
@Override
public void updateText(String someText){
tv_NearRadius.setText(someText);
}
```

Now,
Just pass an interface from your DiscoveryActivity to PopUps class

```
tv_NearRadius.setOnClickListener( v -> {
    PopUps popUps = new PopUps();
    popUps.popDistanceDialog( DiscoverActivity.this, DiscoverActivity.this);
} );


class PopUps{

public void popDistanceDialog( Context context, SomeInfy infy ){


// whatever btnDone operation...
 Btn_Done.setOnClickListener( view -> {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences( AppConstants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE ).edit();
    editor.putInt( AppConstants.PREF_RADIUS, seekbar.getProgress() );
    editor.apply();
    dialog.dismiss();
    
    //
    infy.updateText("whatever");
    
    
} );



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more brutal but can be convenient too. Your dialog has getActivity() method.

Just before dismiss and after saved your preference, use getActivity() method from your dialog. Cast it to your activity and then update your edit text.

Like I said, that raw programming but could suitable to the size of
and structure of your project.

Have fun.